# Projects in Xcode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

Can i create a single project in Xcode such that there are 2 targets, one using C++ and another using Objective-C??

Comment: If you can give a little more detail and context I can probably give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have as many targets as you like, and these can be of any kind. You can also mix languages however you like. You don't need to specify a language for a target though - language is determined by file suffix (although you can customise the behaviour of this).

For source files which need to be compiled for only one or a subset of targets you can use the inspector window targets tab to select which target(s) a given source file is associated with. Select file(s) => `Get Info` => `Targets`.

Comment: Maybe you can add that you can choose what sources to add to which target? Might not be obvious to everyone.